# Android TV App - Google complaining banner does not fill the entire space

Tags: android, android-tv

We are trying to submit a TV only android app to Google play store, but the opt-in for tv is rejected because:

```
No full-size app banner
Your app does not contain a full-size app banner or is it not visible in the launcher. We are targeting 1080P, which we consider xhdpi. Apps should include the banner in the xhdpi (320 dpi) drawables folder with a size of (320px × 180px). Please refer to our Home Screen Banner and UI Patterns documentation.
The title should help users identify apps in the launcher. Please refer to our Visual Design and User Interaction documentation for more information.
For example, your banner does not fill the entire banner space. You can refer to the attached screenshot for additional information
```

They provided a screenshot, although it doesn't display like this according to our tests:

[image: banner]

The banner provided is exactly the correct dimensions, in the drawable-xhdpi directory, saved as 320dpi. Google are unable to help us past this point and we are unsure how to proceed.

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.mypackage">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature
            android:name="android.software.leanback"
            android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
            android:required="false"/>
    <application
            android:name=".MainApplication"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:banner="@drawable/banner"
    >
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".TvActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
        >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category
                        android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

What could be causing this? Any help appreciated!

Comment: I think you are missing this android:banner="@drawable/ic_forward_arrow" in your app's Manifest Application tag.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I've added the manifest file which includes it

Comment: Any solution, I'm facing same issue

Comment: Could anyone solve this issue?