# The application icon is not fully displayed in android tv

Tags: android, flutter, android-tv

I have an app directed to android tv, using flutter to develop this app, and I want to change app banner.

**The problem:**

The banner doesn't fill the rectangle

[image]

**What I tried:**

I add `banner` to `application` tag in `AndroidManifest` like this:

```
<application
        android:label="test"
        android:icon="@drawable/banner"
        android:banner="@drawable/banner"
       >
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68840957/11789675

Comment: is the same qst u r asking ?

Comment: @AnandhKrishnan Yes the same problem but there is no solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check your banner size. The banner should be an xhdpi resource with a size of 320 x 180 px.